# How to solve "This version is not compatible with Drupal 7.x and should be replaced" error?

Tags: .info

I keep getting, "This version is not compatible with Drupal 7.x and should be replaced." error. Could you please look at the content of my .info file and tell me what is wrong with it:

```
name = jeanb
description = sub-theme based on Bartik.
base theme = bartik
engine = phptemplate

stylesheets[all][] = css/jeanb.css

regions[header] = Header
regions[help] = Help
regions[page_top] = Page top
regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted

regions[featured] = Featured
regions[content] = Content
regions[sidebar_first] = Sidebar first
regions[sidebar_second] = Sidebar second

regions[triptych_first] = Triptych first
regions[triptych_middle] = Triptych middle
regions[triptych_last] = Triptych last

regions[footer_firstcolumn] = Footer first column
regions[footer_secondcolumn] = Footer second column
regions[footer_thirdcolumn] = Footer third column
regions[footer_fourthcolumn] = Footer fourth column
regions[footer] = Footer

settings[shortcut_module_link] = 0


; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2013-04-03 
version = "7.22" 
project = "drupal" 
datestamp = "1365027012"
```

Thank you!

Comment: I was about to down vote due to lacking research, but realized, to my surprise, that googling for the error doesn't actually give helpful answers. +1.

Comment: Yep, that's true. And also, I am new to this and I post questions only after having exhausted all other resources (like google-ing, as you mentioned and similar)...So, thanks!

Comment: I was just surprised, I would assume such a basic question would have an answer already, but actually the answers I did find were completely wrong.

Comment: Yea, agreed. In one of the Drupal forums a guy had the same question and they managed to solve the problem by adding: regions[content] = Content part. But this was obviously not the issue in my case. Although Clive gave a correct answer below, I am still confused as the book (on Drupal Themes) clearly said to "delete the lines for package, version, and core." from the .info file.

Comment: David, where did you see that text? It's definitely wrong, and should be fixed. (And as you've noticed, Clive's answer is correct)

Comment: In this book: "Ric Shreves - Drupal 7 Themes - 2011". Page 116: sub-chapter: "Update the sub-theme's .info file"; '3. Delete the lines for package, version, and core.'....Maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: I see, it'll be a bit hard to update a printed book I guess ;) Anyway, glad this whole thing worked out. @Clive perhaps you want to clean up this comment thread. :)

Comment: `; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2013-04-03 "` - this section can confuse Drupal a bit, too. remove it if you use provided stuff as a base. I see that was not the reason of your problem, so I'm posting as a comment and not answer.

Comment: All right. Though, isn't that just a comment? I mean, could commented out lines have any effect?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per [Writing theme .info files](https://drupal.org/node/171205), `core` is a required key. You just need to add

```
core = 7.x
```

to make your theme compatible with Drupal 7.

Comment: It worked. This did it for me. I was fooled by the book "Drupal 7 Themes (Published May 2011, page 116, step 3)" which had told me to delete that line when creating a sub theme. Now, I believe you Clive, not the book. I believe you. :)

Answer (score 7):

You have to include this:

regions[content] = Content

This is new in Drupal 7, now content is a block.

Comment: That was necessary to write besides `core = 7.x` on my 7.31 installation.